# «Ненужный» — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Предложение:

> Для общества станет ненужным.

Слово "нужным" пишется слитно или раздельно с "не"?

Answer (score 2):

**Для общества станет ненужным** [= лишним].

[Ненужный](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/2782) — это прилагательное.

1. Оно образовано от однокоренного слова с помощью приставки **не-** (нужный — нену́жный).
   В предложении новое слово с противоположным значением можно заменить синонимом без приставки: «ненужный» значит «такой, в котором нет нужды», «лишний».
   Пишем слитно.
2. В предложении нет противопоставления или отрицательных слов (наречий или местоимений), а также слов «отнюдь», «вовсе», «далеко».
   Пишем слитно.

[НЕНУЖНЫЙ или НЕ НУЖНЫЙ](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/kogda-pishetsya-nenuzhnyiy-i-ne-nuzhnyiy.html)

Можно сравнить:
*Как перестать чувствовать себя **никому не** нужным?*
*Мы узнали, какие профессии станут **ненужными** через 20 лет.*
Как только он станет **ненужным**, его уберут. [Виктор Левашов. Заговор патриота (2000)]

Answer (score 0):

*Слитно*: здесь по смыслу утверждается качество "ненужный" (=*бесполезный, лишний* в "общественном" смысле), нет явного противопоставления чему-либо "нужному".